# Read text file that has a 2d array and find the sum of each column and add the sum into an array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

Hey guys I want to read a text file that has multiple number similar to a 2d array. I want to find the sum of each column and add it into my int array. I also want to skip the first column and not add it into my int array. For example:

- 0001 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
- 0002 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
- 0003 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

So this would be my text file. I want to read this but skip the first column and add the rest of the column into an int array. So I want my int array[] to look like

- int array[0] = 4
- int array[1] = 7
- int array[2] = 10
- int array[3] = 13
- int array[4] = 16
- int array[5] = 19
- int array[6] = 22
- int array[7] = 25
- int array[8] = 28

So far i have this:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        String fileRead = "";
        int[][] num = null;
        File file = new File("C:\\Users\\Tommy\\Documents\\day.txt");
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(file);
        while(reader.hasNextLine())
            fileRead += reader.nextLine();
        String line = fileRead;
        String[] info = line.split(" ");
        for (int i = 1; i < info.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(info[i]);        
        }
}
```

My code isnt finished because i dont know how to add column. But so far its printing the first row and skipping 0001. but then it prints the second row and doesnt skip 0002. So the output for my code so far looks like:

- 1
- 2
- 3
- 4
- 5
- 6
- 7
- 8

but then it prints

- 90002
- 1
- 2
- 3
- 4

etc.
Any clue on how i can solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Your `fileRead` variable get the first line, and in the second line it concatenations the second line immediately, so the string look like this:

..90002 1 ..

You just need insert a space in the while loop.

```
while(reader.hasNextLine())
            fileRead += reader.nextLine();
            fileRead += “ “;
```

EDIT

```
while(reader.hasNextLine()){
    fileRead += reader.nextLine();
    fileRead +=‘$’;


String line = fileRead;
String[] infoRow = line.split("$");
int[] results = new int[9];

for (int i = 0; i< infoRow.length;i++){
        string[] info = infoRow[i].split(" ");
        for (int j = 1; j < info.length; j++){
              results[j-1] += Integer.parseInt(info[j]);  
            }
    }
for (int i = 0; i< results.length;i++){
    System.out.println(results[i]);
}
```

Comment: So i added and got the same result. Could this be because of the split delimiter?

Comment: My answer is wrong, you new insert a delimiter different from space. 

You should inser for exapmle dollar sign, and the iterate over 2d array, the first is split by $, and the second on by space.  

I will fix my answer

Comment: I dont know how to do that. Sorry im new to coding. I just want to be able to skip the first column entirely and then find the sum of column 2 add it to array[0], sum of column 3 add it to array[1] and so on. Any easy way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this. Here is one way that does it as you process the input file.

```
int[] sums = computeSums("C:\\Users\\Tommy\\Documents\\day.txt");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sums));
```

prints

```
[4, 7, 10, 13, 16, 19, 22, 25, 28]
```

Here is how the file is processed.

- Continue doing the following lines while lines are available for processing.

  - if the `sums` field is null, this is first time thru so read in the first line, skipping the first int, and then using streams, create an `int array` which is assigned to `sums`.
  - otherwise, skip the first `int` of the following lines and read the rest of the line as ints adding them to the corresponding sums column.

```
public static int[] computeSums(String fileName) {
     int[] sums = null;

     try {
         Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(fileName));

         while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
             scanner.nextInt(); // skip first value
             // read in the next line, trimming leading white space, to ensure
             // splitting on int boundaries. Then use the String array to get proper size
             // the sums array.
             
             if (sums == null) {
                 String[] vals = scanner.nextLine().trim().split("\\s+");
                 sums = new int[vals.length];
                 
             // now populate the sums array with the first row (line) of the file
                 int i = 0;
                 for (String val : vals) {
                     sums[i++] = Integer.parseInt(val);
                 }
             } else {
             // from now until the end of the file, simply read the next value
             // and add to the corresponding sums column
                 for (int i = 0; i < sums.length; i++) {
                     sums[i] += scanner.nextInt();
                 }
             }
         }
        
     } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
         fnfe.printStackTrace();
     }
     return sums;
}
```

Note:  Since you didn't specify how to handle different row lengths of the same 2D array, this only works if array is rectangular.  Otherwise an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` will be thrown.